# Replace a selected text in contentEditable div with html-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `contectEditable` div and button, and want when I select a text in the div like this ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-keller-42iu2?file=/src/App.js))
[image]

and then press the button, to replace the selected text with a span html element with the selected text as content. For example, I have this React component

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const EdiatbelContent = () => {

    const onClickhandler () => {};
    
    const [html, setHtml] = useState("<p>Hello World!</p>");
    
    return <>
       <div contentEditable="true" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}></div>
       <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Bold</button>
    </>

}

export default EditableContent;
```

I want when I press the button, to replace the selected text (if any is selected), say the word `Hello` in the example above, with the span html element `<span className="text-bold">Hello</span>` so that the html state variable becomes

```
<p><span className="text-bold">Hello</span> World!</p>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I have got the question correctly, you can use the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) to access the user's selection and use its properties to achieve what you want. Here is the bit of code that could get you started:

```
const onClickHandler = () => {
      // get user's selection
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      // get the start and end index of selection
      // remember user can select backwards
      let startIndex = selection.anchorOffset;
      let endIndex = selection.focusOffset;
      if (startIndex > endIndex) {
        startIndex = selection.focusOffset;
        endIndex = selection.anchorOffset;
      }
      // now get the text before and after the selection
      const beforeSelection = html.substring(0, startIndex);
      const afterSelection = html.substring(endIndex, html.length);
      // and set the html as you see fit
      setHtml(`${beforeSelection}<span className="text-bold">${selection.toString()}</span>${afterSelection}`)
};
```

This of course is the most basic form, you need to take a lot of edge cases into consideration.

Comment: OK, this is a start, but your code is not working when I apply it to the codesandbox I provided above.

Comment: @BlackMath why not, what is wrong? if the result text is not correct, you need to count in that <p> tag at the beginning, so since it is 3 characters, you need to add 3 to start and end index, but this is not a good approach. You need to make a distinction between the underlying text and the HTML presented in the screen. I just wanted to give you the starting point, you can debug and build up from there.